# Is there a way to delay my web scraper before it scrapes the page?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So here is my function :

```
def clubList(url,yearCode):
    print(url + "/clubs" + yearCode)
    response = requests.get(url + "/clubs" + yearCode)
    time.sleep(10)
    content = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    cluburl = []
    clubs = []
    ul = soup.find_all(
        "ul",
        attrs={
            "class": "block-list-5 block-list-3-m block-list-1-s block-list-1-xs block-list-padding dataContainer"
        },
    )
    u = str(ul)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(u, "html.parser")
    for i, tags in enumerate(soup2.find_all("a")):
        cluburl.append(url + str(tags.get("href")))
    for i in range(0, len(cluburl)):
        cluburl[i] = cluburl[i].replace("overview", "squad")
    return cluburl
```

I'm trying to scrape the Premier league website to build a stat database for a data analysis project.

My current link tree looks like:

https://www.premierleague.com -> https://www.premierleague.com/clubs -> https://www.premierleague.com/clubs?se=418

The "?se=418" is the access code that I add to the link to specify which season's stats I would like to view, with each season having its own unique code.

I pass " https://www.premierleague.com " as the url and "?se=418" as the yearCode to my function, and it should return the list of links to the individual club's pages for that particular season.
However, it always returns the club link list for the current season.

I've noticed that when I directly access the link https://www.premierleague.com/clubs?se=418 it first loads in the current season clubs and then dynamically refreshes in the appropriate ones.

So I thought adding a time delay might do the trick but I guess it is parsing the contents of the page in the requests.get statement and I'm not sure where I should add my delay to make this work.

Also here are all the modules you'll have to import to run the function:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import locale
import time

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF8")
```

Comment: *dynamically refreshes* implies javascript. You can retry the call by using something like a `for _ in range(2)` with a `time.sleep(3)` after the first call. If that doesn't update, then you might need something like selenium to render the javascript through the browser

Comment: @C.Nivs

@C.Nivs

I tried modifying the statement like this:
`for i in range(3):`
        `response = requests.get(url + "/clubs" + yearCode)`
        `time.sleep(3)`
        `i+=1 `
but that didnt work, I'm not sure if this is what you meant. 

also im sorry if my edits spammed you with notifications, im new to making comments and posts on here and not just googling and finding my answer here immediately

Comment: Sounds like selenium is going to be the way, you need a browser to render and refresh the javascript. [To the docs!](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#introduction)

Comment: @C.Nivs okay so I've tried implementing a fix with selenium `wd.get(link)` 
`wd.implicitly_wait(10)`
`content =wd.page_source` this was along the same lines as i was thinking previously, but im still getting the same output. Could you guide me in the right direction on what i might need to do?

Comment: *it should return the list of links to the individual club's pages for that particular season.* - I don't see any links that gives such data. All the club links are showing the current seasons data. Could you elaborate more on that ? An example URL will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform a season filter, it uses the following API:

```
GET https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/teams
```

It needs the following http headers to return the data: `account: premierleague` and `origin: https://www.premierleague.com`

The following example uses the API to get the club list, and then extract club id and club name to generate the club url:

```py
import requests

season = 418

r = requests.get("https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/teams", 
    params = {
        "pageSize": 100,
        "compSeasons": season,
        "compCodeForActivePlayer": "null",
        "comps": 1,
        "altIds": "true",
        "page": 0
    },
    headers = {
        "account": "premierleague",
        "origin": "https://www.premierleague.com"
    }
)

data = r.json()
print([
    f'https://www.premierleague.com/clubs/{int(t["club"]["id"])}/{t["club"]["name"].replace(" ","-")}/squad'
    for t in data["content"]
])
```

Comment: could you please link me to anymore documentation on the api used here, I tried googling it but it led me to a paid service, I need to use the filter option on individual squads as well to get the right team. So I might have to get a different link and pass different parameters

Comment: @ManishAG I didn't found it in the documentation. I just looked at the http calls in the network tabs of Chrome development console